# Parsing xml and forcing ASCII encoding

Tags: php, xml, unicode, fonts, simplexml

I am trying to parse an svg font file in PHP for analysis and loading to a database. I am parsing with SimpleXMLElement.

```
$fontXML = simplexml_load_file($font_url);
```

However, SimpleXML is being very nice and converts unicode strings, such as "&#x164", into a character. Normally this is great, however, because an svg font file is, in effect, an ASCII representation of the the unicode (and other) mapping, it must be treated as ASCII text.

Consider the following example tag:

```
<glyph glyph-name="Tcaron_h" unicode="&#x164;h" horiz-adv-x="1129" d="M776 292v-216c0 ..." />
```

With SimpleXML, when I call (string)$myGlyphElement['unicode'] I get a string of four characters (because &#x164 is a compound character of two characters). This causes all sorts of headaches.

Any suggestions how to force SimpleXML to work in pure ASCII encoding, or an alternative parsing methods, short of writing an XML parser.

I can, of course, modify the string of the xml to fool the parser that this is not unicode, but I think that it is better to avoid such hacks if other, more intuitive approaches are available.

Comment: This isn't actually about ASCII vs Unicode, it's about entities (`&...;`) vs string data. I'm not sure how to solve your specific problems, but there's no "pure ASCII" version of `&#x164;`. Possibly you just need to run `html_entities` over the string to turn it back into an XML-escaped version before doing whatever it is you want to do next.

Comment: Alternatively, your headaches may have to do with Unicode, but nothing to do with XML, in which case you need to examine which parts of your system aren't handling the string correctly, and use something like `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` to change its representation, or the `mb` and `intl` functions to handle it differently.